# How do I use multiple classes to modify a single data source without declaring it as a global?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm looking to create multiple class instances that all share a single source of data, in this case an object.  Unfortunately I can't seem to get this to work without using the object as a global variable.

So I'm wondering if there a more sophisticated solution to the following?

```js
let amount = {
  needed: 0,
}

class Store {
    constructor(a) {
     this.needed = a.needed;
    }
    
    addNeeded(x) {
     amount.needed += x;
        this.needed += x;
    }
    
    getNeeded() {
      return {
        amount: amount.needed,
        store: this.needed
      }
    }
}

const test1 = new Store(amount);
const test2 = new Store(amount);

test1.addNeeded(5); // this.needed returns 5, amount.needed is now 5
console.log(test1.getNeeded(), amount.needed);

test2.addNeeded(10); // this.needed return 10, amount.needed is now 15
console.log(test2.getNeeded(), amount.needed);
```

As you can see, **this.needed** will create a copy of **amount.needed** in it's own instance if I pass the object to it's constructor.  I feel like I'm missing something very elementary, and there's a more elegant solution here.

Comment: have you considered using prototype?

Comment: I'd prefer not to use prototype, this is for a mobx store.

Answer (score 2):

Since `amount` is an object, you can store a reference to it, and update it via the reference:

```js
const amount = {
  needed: 0,
}

class Store {
  constructor(amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
  }

  addNeeded(x) {
    this.amount.needed += x;
  }

  getNeeded() {
    return {
      needed: this.amount.needed,
    }
  }
}

const test1 = new Store(amount);
const test2 = new Store(amount);

test1.addNeeded(5); // this.needed returns 5, amount.needed is now 5
console.log(test1.getNeeded(), amount.needed);
test2.addNeeded(10); // this.needed return 15, amount.needed is now 15
console.log(test2.getNeeded(), amount.needed);
```

Another option is to set `amount` as a static class property ([requires babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties/)).

**Note:** if you don't want (or can't) use static class properties, you can set it manually on the class `Store.amount = { needed: 0 }`.

```js
class Store {
  static amount = {
    needed: 0,
  };

  constructor(amount) {
    this.needed = Store.amount.needed;
  }

  addNeeded(x) {
    Store.amount.needed += x;
  }

  getNeeded() {
    return {
      needed: Store.amount.needed,
    }
  }
}

// Store.amount = { needed: 0 } // instead of using static

const test1 = new Store();
const test2 = new Store();

test1.addNeeded(5); // this.needed returns 5, amount.needed is now 5
console.log(test1.getNeeded(), Store.amount.needed);
test2.addNeeded(10); // this.needed return 15, amount.needed is now 15
console.log(test2.getNeeded(), Store.amount.needed);
```

Comment: or without using babel, you can just use `if ( ! Store.amount ) Store.amount = { needed: 0 };` at the beginning of the constructor.

Comment: Or just `Store.amount = { needed: 0 }` outside after declaring the class.

Comment: Yeah, that's even better.

Comment: "*Another option is to set amount as a static class property*" - no, don't do that, it's essentially creating a global variable (not in the global scope, but with a globally shared value, which is *bad™* for mutable values).

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a reason to store a separate `.needed` value on the instance and always modify both the instance property and the wrapped object property. At best, use a getter/setter.

Comment: @bergi - I agree with both comments. However, the OP actually wants a shared value, and it's part of the original design to have the value in both places. How would you tackle both requests in another way?

Comment: @OriDrori I don't think he requested a `.needed` instance property, he just complained that it would create a copy (that he didn't want, he was looking for a reference).

Comment: @Bergi - sounds reasonable. Although it it's not that obvious in the question. My thought was that he wants to maintain a separate sum, and a global sum.Anyway, it doesn't change the shared nature of amount.